# iOS8 UIToolbar disappearing when showing detail view controller

Tags: storyboard, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller, uitoolbar

I'm working with an app using a `UISplitViewController` as the window's root. I would like both the master and the detail view controllers to be a `UITableViewController` inside of a `UINavigationController`, with the `UIToolbar` visible. In a horizontally regular size width, this works fine, as displayed:

[image: iPad 2]

The problem is in a horizontally compact size class, where the `UISplitViewController` is pushing the detail view controller onto a stack like a `UINavigationController`, the toolbar disappears as the detail is being shown, and reappears after the detail is fully popped (see below). I'd like for the toolbar to remain in place as it does with a normal navigation controller.

[image]

Sample project uploaded [here](https://github.com/markcleonard/SplitView).

Comment: add many rows and scroll down then select - the glitch is even worse, the selected row shifts down by a whole toolbar height.

Answer (score 6):

For this initial implementation, I think Apple chose to hide the master's toolbar, since the (primary) navigation controller can't use a single toolbar to both be onscreen, and be sliding (different items) onscreen.  If you look at Apple's Mail app, their primary toolbar disappears during the push animation, just like you're seeing.

Interestingly, their Calendar app uses a really nice toolbar crossFade between day and event view controller transitions.  If you look at that animation, you can see that it's a single toolbar for both views, instead of a second toolbar animating above the first.

Although crossFade is privately supported by `UINavigationController`, Apple doesn't enable it for this particular view controller animation.  `_shouldCrossFadeBottomBars` returns NO, and there's no setter for the `delegateShouldCrossFadeBottomBars` navigation controller flag.

I'd submit a bug report along with an enhancement request to support bottom bar animation for a unified storyboard `UISplitViewController`.  I believe Apple will improve the iPhone's split view controller functionality.

In the meantime, you can handle this by hiding the primary navigation controller's toolbar, and add a toolbar to the master view controller's storyboard.  This will allow the master view controller's own toolbar to be onscreen, while the detail view controller's toolbar items slide in.

This will involve changing your master's `UITableViewController` to a `UIViewController`.  Add a `UIToolbar` and constraints.  For the table, you can drop in a `UITableView`, or use a container view and connect it to your `UITableviewController`.

Setup your detail view's toolbar in `DetailViewController`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init ...];
    self.toolbarItems = @[barButtonItem];

    [self configureView];
}
```

The navigation controller will have setup the toolbar items (after the view has loaded but) before the view appears, and the toolbar will be pushed onto the screen along with the detail view.

If you're curious, here's what I understand to be going on with the detail view's toolbar for the horizontally compact size class.  It's the secondary navigation controller, *not* the detail view controller, that gets pushed onto the primary navigation controller stack.  The primary navigation controller picks up its decoration from the secondary navigation controller, along with the `navigationItems` (and `toolbarItems`) belonging to its visible (detail) view controller.

Unfortunately, the trickery behind the scenes to collapse the split view's secondary (navigation) controller affects your toolbar, because the primary navigation controller took over for what the secondary navigation controller was handling.

All we've done is move the secondary toolbar from the secondary navigation controller to the detail view controller, so the primary navigation controller can handle the detail view controller's toolbar animation as the secondary navigation controller is pushed.

Perhaps in a future update, the split view controller will be able to animate the storyboard's toolbar, but for now, the only way I know how to do it is in code.

Comment: Very nice explanation; clear, profound. "It's the secondary navigation controller, not the detail view controller, that gets pushed onto the primary navigation controller stack." Correct. I commented on this, with some surprise that it works at all, here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1056959#1056959 Useful response from an Apple insider there.

Comment: Maybe, but I'd have to go back and figure it out. Right now I just want to get through the first draft! If you know how to do it, maybe you could make an example project on github that I can steal from...? :)

Comment: Wow. That certainly is an documentation omission. They might have said something about this in any of several adaptation-related WWDC 2014 videos...! Of course they have also never said anything about this, and yet it turns out to be crucial: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26591842/341994

Comment: Peter - I'd like to add this info as a note in the navigation controllers chapter. Do you want to be credited by name?

Comment: Does the solution listed in the answer actually solve the issue of the disappearing UIToolbar? In my testing it does not.

Comment: @PetahChristian Interesting, cause I can't get it to work. I did set the toolbarItems for the MasterViewController in it's viewDidLoad-Method and the toolbarItems for the DetailViewController also in ViewDidLoad. However, when the DetailViewController gets pushed, the Toolbar of the MasterViewController still disappears and only reappears, when the DetailViewController gets popped.

Comment: @PetahChristian Sorry, to ask again. I forked Mark Leonards original sample project here: https://github.com/hholtmann/SplitView It demonstrates, that the toolbar hide issue still exists - even when the toolbarItems for the DetailView are set in viewDidLoad. Maybe you have a hint about what to change. I have tried everything possible for several hours with no success.

Comment: @PetahChristia Thanks a lot for looking into this issue. It shocks me that apple released all this stuff without even testing the most common scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use the Master-Detail Application without changing the default View Controllers and you are ok with the toolbar disappearing when pushing to the Detail View Controller... you can add the following line of code to the Master View Controller in viewWillAppear so that when it pops back the toolbar is there during the segue, not waiting to appear until after the segue is done.

```
self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)
```

Of course you can delete the default Table View Controller and use a standard View Controller with a table view in it and add a toolbar, then you don't have the issue. It does break a line of code since it is no longer in a Table View Controller and a standard Navigation Controller doesn't support clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear.

```
tableView.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = self.splitViewController!.collapsed
```

You can fix that by adding this code to your viewWillAppear...

```
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: FYI table view controller does a lot more than clearing selection, and it's clear is an interactive animation too not a simple deselect.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
UINavigationController *secondaryNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableViewController];
[secondaryNavigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
[self showDetailViewController:secondaryNavigationController sender:nil];
```

`self` in this case is a subclassed UISplitViewController.

On pushing the secondary (detail) view controller, the toolbar attached to the primary view controller stays where it is, and just fades out. On popping the secondary view controller, the toolbar attached to the primary view controller fades back in.