# iOS state restoration animation bug

Tags: ios, state-restoration

I just wanted to implement the iOS State-Restoration APIs in one of my Apps.
After finally getting it to work, I discovered that a ViewController that I present modally gets restored using an animation, which is not what I want. I would expect my app to just be in the state I left it, but not having the user to see hot he got there.

So I went ahead and downloaded Apple Sample Code on that: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/StateRestore/Introduction/Intro.html and wanted to see if it happens there as well. And it turns out that it does.

Further there is a warning in the Logs:

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UINavigationController: 0x7b0512b0>.
```

Can you tell me if I and obviously Apples Sample Code are doing something wrong, or if it's a bug in iOS?

Btw. I was testing on iOS8

Thanks for any help,
Georg

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following solution comes directly from Apple.

In your app delegate, you should be implementing `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (instead of or in addition to `didFinishLaunching`). In your implementation, probably as the last line just before returning `true` (or YES if this is Objective-C), insert this line:

```
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Or, if this is Objective-C:

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

It turns out that this was *always* needed, but the documentation has never been clear about it.

Comment: The Apple same code you cited actually does this now, so I'm not sure why you're seeing the problem there.

Comment: Yay. Adding a bounty to questions works! The Apple code calls `makeKeyAndVisible` inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` instead of `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Moving it to `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` makes everything work properly. Thank you! I'll award the bounty in 23 hours (Stack Overflow doesn't let me do it now).

Comment: @bogdansrc Your eyes are sharper than mine! You're perfectly right: the Apple sample code does the right thing _in the wrong place_, and that's why it didn't solve the problem. The funny thing is that the comment they inserted before that line shows clearly that they _thought_ they were putting it in the right place: "require the window being visible before state restoration." Exactly so; but "before state restoration" means before the end of `willFinish`! That's the whole point of that code! It would be worth filing a bug report about that (if you feel like it).

Comment: Apple never felt like fixing bugs for the reports I filed, so I no longer feel like filing them. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @bogdansrc I know how you feel. However, the solution I gave you came from Apple's response to my own bug report on this very issue - so you see, bug reports do sometimes work.

Comment: I am having the state restoration animation issue in iOS 13 with modal controllers; since we can no longer call makeKeyAndVisible for window in iOS 13 (with scenes), is there some sort of comparable way to handle this in iOS 13?

Answer (score 1):

From documentation:
[Preserving Your App’s Visual Appearance Across Launches](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW26)

See the 3rd item from the checklist below.

**Checklist for Implementing State Preservation and Restoration**

Supporting state preservation and restoration requires modifying your app delegate and view controller objects to encode and decode the state information. If your app has any custom views that also have preservable state information, you need to modify those objects too.

When adding state preservation and restoration to your code, use the following list to remind you of the code you need to write.

- (Required) Implement the application:shouldSaveApplicationState: and
  application:shouldRestoreApplicationState: methods in your app
  delegate; see Enabling State Preservation and Restoration in Your
  App.
- (Required) Assign restoration identifiers to each view controller you
  want to preserve by assigning a non empty string to their
  restorationIdentifier property; see Marking Your View Controllers for
  Preservation.

  If you want to save the state of specific views too, assign non empty
  strings to their restorationIdentifier properties; see Preserving the
  State of Your Views.
- (Required) Show your app’s window from the
  application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method of your app
  delegate. The state restoration machinery needs the window so that it
  can restore scroll positions and other relevant bits of your app’s
  interface.
- Assign restoration classes to the appropriate view controllers. (If
  you do not do this, your app delegate is asked to provide the
  corresponding view controller at restore time.) See Restoring Your
  View Controllers at Launch Time.
- (Recommended) Encode and decode the state of your views and view
  controllers using the encodeRestorableStateWithCoder: and
  decodeRestorableStateWithCoder: methods of those objects; see
  Encoding and Decoding Your View Controller’s State.
- Encode and decode any version information or additional state
  information for your app using the
  application:willEncodeRestorableStateWithCoder: and
  application:didDecodeRestorableStateWithCoder: methods of your app
  delegate; see Preserving Your App’s High-Level State.
- Objects that act as data sources for table views and collection views
  should implement the UIDataSourceModelAssociation protocol. Although
  not required, this protocol helps preserve the selected and visible
  items in those types of views. See Implementing Preservation-Friendly
  Data Sources.

Answer (score -1):

Apple sample code seems to work fine on Xcode 8.

So I suppose no additional code changes would be required